# Before Update Trigger fails

Tags: apex, trigger, event, before-trigger

I am trying to run a trigger on before update on the knowledge records and I tried like below

```
trigger concertHTMLToLongText on Knowledge__kav(before update) {
  List<id> knowIds = new List<id>();
  for (Knowledge__kav con : Trigger.New) {
    knowIds.add(con.Id);
  }
  List<Knowledge__kav> knowled = [
    SELECT Id, Legacy_Solution__c, Article_Body_Long_T__c
    FROM Knowledge__kav
    WHERE ID IN :knowIds
  ];
  for (Knowledge__kav kn : knowled) {
    Solution sol = [
      SELECT SolutionNote
      FROM Solution
      WHERE ID = :kn.Legacy_Solution__c
    ];
    kn.Article_Body_Long_T__c = sol.SolutionNote;
    update kn;
  }
}
```

Got the error like `concertHTMLToLongText: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id ka03C0000000gPSQAY; first error: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object (id = ka03C0000000gPS) is currently in trigger concertHTMLToLongText, therefore it cannot recursively update itself: [] Trigger.concertHTMLToLongText: line 17, column 1`

Read that in the before update event if we have DML execution we need to be doing all the operation within the `Trigger.New` changed the trigger like below

```
trigger concertHTMLToLongText on Knowledge__kav(before update) {
  for (Knowledge__kav con : Trigger.New) {
    List<Knowledge__kav> knowled = [
      SELECT Id, Legacy_Solution__c, Article_Body_Long_T__c
      FROM Knowledge__kav
      WHERE ID = :con.Id
    ];
    for (Knowledge__kav kn : knowled) {
      Solution sol = [
        SELECT SolutionNote
        FROM Solution
        WHERE ID = :kn.Legacy_Solution__c
      ];
      kn.Article_Body_Long_T__c = sol.SolutionNote;
      update kn;
    }
  }
}
```

And getting the errors `Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id ka03C0000000gPSQAY; first error: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object (id = ka03C0000000gPS) is currently in trigger concertHTMLToLongText, therefore it cannot recursively update itself:` . Please help me how I can resolve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not perform a DML operation directly. Simply assigning the value is enough. When the before trigger completes, any changes to Trigger.new are committed to the database.

You should bulkify your code, however. Here's a fixed version:

```
trigger concertHTMLToLongText on Knowledge__kav(before update) {
  Map<Id, Solution> solutions = new Map<Id, Solution>();

  for (Knowledge__kav con : Trigger.New) {
    solutions.put(con.Legacy_Solution__c, null);
  }
  solutions.putAll(
    [SELECT SolutionNote FROM Solution WHERE Id = :solutions.keySet()]
  );
  for (Knowledge__kav con : Trigger.new) {
    Solution result = solutions.get(con.Legacy_Solution__c);
    if (result != null) {
      con.Article_Body_Long_T__c = result.SolutionNote;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Doesnt the for loop here bulkify the trigger.

Comment: @user81642 Mine is bulkified, yes. I was merely calling out that yours was not; you should always avoid putting queries in loops if you can help it.

Answer (score 0):

You are in a before update trigger. You then query for the record that is in the trigger and try to update it. This causes a recursive call to update the record which is not allowed.

Comment: How can I approach this, I cannot do after update

Comment: Put your logic into another class and call it asynchronously.